# $instance in wordpress widget form method is null

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress widget development and learning from [tutsplus videos](http://tutsplus.com/course/wordpress-plugin-development-essentials/) on the go. I am trying to create a simple widget for my website. So far I am following every steps from the video but still I am getting following error and the form is not saving the values.

```
Warning: extract() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\Program Files\Ampps\www\test\wp-content\plugins\first\index.php on line 50
```

This is the from method

```
public function form($instance){ 
extract($instance);
?>
        <p>
            <lable for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('ap_title_text');?>">Title Text: </lable>
            <input type="text" class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('ap_title_text');?>"  name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('ap_title_text');?>" value="<?php if(isset($ap_title_text)) echo esc_attr($ap_title_text);?>" />
        </p>

<?php
```

So far, I have just created the constructor and registered the widget. There was no error displayed till this step in the video. And every website I googled for this problem showed similar steps. I don't understand why it is showing error on my system.
I am using wordpress 3.5.2 downloaded yesterday and using php5.3.

**EDIT ::**
Here is the code.

```
class SidebarWidget extends WP_Widget{

    function __construct()
    {
        $options = array(
        'description'   =>  'Simplest way to start working from any page',
        'name'          =>  'Sidebar Widget'
        );
        parent::__construct('appSidebarWidget', '', $options);
    }

    public function form($instance)
    {   
        extract($instance);
        ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('ap_title_text'); ?>" >Title Text: </lable>
            <input type="text" class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('ap_title_text');?>"  name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('ap_title_text');?>" value="<?php if(isset($ap_title_text)) echo esc_attr($ap_title_text);?>" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('ap_app_name'); ?>" >app Name: </lable>
            <input type="text" class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('ap_app_name');?>"    name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('ap_app_name');?>"   value="<?php if(isset($ap_app_name)) echo esc_attr($ap_app_name);?>" />
        </p>

        <?php
    }

    public function widget($args, $instance)
    {

        extract($args);
        extract($instance);
        $display_gadget = "<iframe src='http://$appURL' width='150px' height='200px' scrolling='auto' frameborder='0' allowtransparency='true'></iframe>";

        if(empty($ap_title_text)){$ap_title_text = "Schedule Now";}
        echo $before_widget;
            echo $before_title.$ap_title_text.$after_title;
            echo $display_gadget;
        echo $after_widget;
    }

}

add_action('widgets_init','appRegisterWidget');
function appRegisterWidget()
{
    register_widget('appSidebarWidget');
}
```

I still haven't been able to get it working. However the actual project for which i was learning this, works as expected. I would still like to know what is wrong with this one. I nearly lost my job because of this.

Also, can anyone guide me to call a custom javascript function from a button on widget being displayed. Basically my purpose is to display a button on the widget rendered by the information on the form. When someone click the button, It should display an overlay with message.

Comment: Anyone available to help me. I have tried completing the code but still the widget shows same error. I even tried print_r($instance) but no solution.

Comment: Please post the full code of your widget class at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

In the following code

```
add_action('widgets_init','appRegisterWidget');
function appRegisterWidget()
{
    register_widget('appSidebarWidget'); <--
}
```

Change it to

```
register_widget('SidebarWidget');
```

I've added a url `text box` in the widget setup form and it's working, (full modified code given below)

```
class SidebarWidget extends WP_Widget{
    function __construct()
    {
        $options = array(
            'description'   =>  'Simplest way to start working from any page',
            'name'          =>  'Sidebar Widget'
        );
        parent::__construct('appSidebarWidget', '', $options);
    }

    public function form($instance)
    {   
        extract($instance);
        ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('ap_title_text'); ?>" >Title Text: </lable>
            <input type="text" class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('ap_title_text');?>"  name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('ap_title_text');?>" value="<?php if(isset($ap_title_text)) echo esc_attr($ap_title_text);?>" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('ap_app_name'); ?>" >App Name: </lable>
            <input type="text" class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('ap_app_name');?>"    name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('ap_app_name');?>"   value="<?php if(isset($ap_app_name)) echo esc_attr($ap_app_name);?>" />
        </p>
        <!-- New text box added -->
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('ap_app_url'); ?>" >App Url: </lable>
            <input type="text" class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('ap_app_url');?>"    name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('ap_app_url');?>"   value="<?php if(isset($ap_app_url)) echo esc_attr($ap_app_url);?>" />
        </p>

        <?php
    }

    public function widget($args, $instance)
    {
        extract($args);
        extract($instance);
        $display_gadget = "<iframe src='http://" . $ap_app_url . "' width='150px' height='200px' scrolling='auto' frameborder='0' allowtransparency='true'></iframe>";

        if(empty($ap_title_text)){$ap_title_text = "Schedule Now";}
        echo $before_widget;
        echo $before_title.$ap_title_text.$after_title;
        echo $display_gadget;
        echo $after_widget;
    }

}

add_action('widgets_init','appRegisterWidget');
function appRegisterWidget()
{
    register_widget('SidebarWidget');
}
```

### Screen shot of working example given below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The code is crashing because the variable `$instance` is not an array. The `extract()` function has to receive an array in order to do it's job. That much is clear and very simple.

The problem is that nobody can help you explain why `$instance` is null unless you provide the code which calls the `form()` function. There could be a million reasons why `$instance` is not an array.

Answer (score 0):

The form() function is being called by the WP_Widgets object.

Answer (score 0):

`$instance` could also always be null in the form method if you have an **empty update function**. This may not relate to this question, but please check whether that is the issue if you run into a similar issue.